# How to draw on the background of a figure in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot, annotations, matlab-figure, subplot

I have a 6-by-3 set of subplots where two subplots are always related. I want to change the background color behind two of these plots (not the background of plots themselves) to "connect" them optically.

I tried it with a rectangle annotation but there is no way to get it behind the plots. `uistack` didn't work either. Using the `'bottom'` option, the rectangle is still in front of the plots.

Is there any way to draw on the background behind plots?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a little example of how you might do this with [`axes`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes.html) to create an axis with a colored background and [`uistack`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uistack.html) to move it to the back:

```
figure
h1 = subplot(2,2,1);
h2 = subplot(2,2,2);
h3 = subplot(2,2,3);
h4 = subplot(2,2,4);

p1 = get(h1,'Position');
p2 = get(h2,'Position');
border = 0.3*p1(1);
x1 = p1(1)-border;
y1 = p1(2)-border;
width1 = p2(3)+p2(1)-p1(1)+2*border;     
height1 = max(p1(4),p2(4))+2*border;
ax1 = axes('Position', [x y width1 height1],...
           'Color','r','XTick',[],'XColor','r','YTick',[],'YColor','r');
uistack(ax1,'bottom')

p3 = get(h3,'Position');
p4 = get(h4,'Position');
border = 0.3*p3(1);
x2 = p3(1)-border;
y2 = p3(2)-border;
width2 = p4(3)+p4(1)-p3(1)+2*border;
height2 = max(p3(4),p4(4))+2*border;
ax2 = axes('Position', [x2 y2 width2 height2],...
           'Color','b','XTick',[],'XColor','b','YTick',[],'YColor','b');
uistack(ax2,'bottom')
```

This produces a figure that looks like this one :
[image: figure window]

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks a lot. I still have some little problems because I use subplot_tight from FileExchange but I'm sure that I can fix them.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply set the `Color` property of each axes object to the color you like. For example:

```
subplot(2,2,1)
plot(1:3,1:3) % example plot
set(gca,'Color',[.5 .5 .8]) % set background color
subplot(2,2,2)
plot(1:3,1:3)
set(gca,'Color',[.5 .5 .8]) % set background color
subplot(2,2,3)
plot(1:3,1:3)
subplot(2,2,4)
plot(1:3,1:3)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your idea. It could be an option but the background of the plots has to be white. I actually want to color the space between the two blue plots and the two white plots.

Comment: Oh, I see. Much harder, it seems